# Twitter Gem for Rails wont bring back Tweets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am using the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) for a Rails 4.2 Project running on Ruby 2.2.1. I have the following code:

```
  def fetch_aisis_writer_tweets
    # Cache the tweets and expire after 5 minutes.
    data = Rails.cache.fetch([:aisis_twitter_feed, Time.now.to_i/60/5], expires_in: 15.seconds){
      tweet_array = [];
      tweet = twitter_client.search("#AisisWriter").take(10).each do |tweet|
        tweet_array.push(tweet)
      end
    }

    render json: data
  end
```

Which is returning an empty array of tweets. running the `twitter_client.search("#AisisWriter").take(10)` returns nothing. How ever if we go to twitter and search for the particular hashtag, [#AisisWriter](https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=%23AisisWriter&src=typd&lang=en) We can see that I do indeed get back a multitude of tweets containing this hashtag.

So why is the code above returning an empty array of tweets?

**Update**

So some people below suggested I use [Streaming API](https://github.com/tweetstream/tweetstream). So I updated my code to show the new data object using their code example and the streaming api.

```
  def fetch_aisis_writer_tweets
    # Cache the tweets and expire after 5 minutes.
    data = Rails.cache.fetch([:aisis_twitter_feed, Time.now.to_i/60/5], expires_in: 15.seconds){
      tweet_array = [];

      tweet = twitter_stream.filter(track: '#AisisWriter') do |streamed_tweet|
        tweet_array.push(streamed_tweet)
      end
    }

    render json: data
  end
```

But alas, nothing happens, the console just shows:

```
Processing by Api::Internal::TwitterController#fetch_aisis_writer_tweets as */*
```

and the page just keeps trying to load. **At the end of the day I just want the latest 10 tweets from this particular hash tag.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search:

> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

That could explain why `twitter_client.search("#AisisWriter").take(10)` is returning an empty array.

`twitter_client.search` is not a streaming API end point.

Assuming `twitter_client` is defined as a `Twitter::Streaming::Client` object, the following should work (assuming there are new tweets with `#AisisWriter`:

```
twitter_client.filter(track: "#AisisWriter") do |object|
  puts object.text if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
end
```

Comment: If you look closely to what I have set up: I have created the streaming client  which is documented here https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Streaming.md in that example. Not sure how using a different gem would help, it also doesn't show how to do a search result and stream the result.

Comment: You're using search- that is not a streaming api end point. Use filter.

Comment: Please see updated post. this does not work. It doesn't even show me an error.

Comment: Try the same with a more active hashtag - for example in any in the top trends - `#CWC15` , `Happy Palm Sunday`, etc. That will show you lot of activity. There is not really much happening in the `#AisisWriter` tag, and for some reason the old tweets in that tag are not being included.